# Get week number by year and month

Tags: vb.net

How to get Firstdayofweek and Lastdayofweek based on given year and month and week number (week number of that month)?

I am able to get FirstdayofWeek, but when I try for February (2018, 2, 1) with week 2 the output date is incorrect.

```
Dim firstDayOfWeek As date
firstDayOfWeek = DateSerial(2018, 2, 1) 'february 2018
firstDayOfWeek = DateAdd("ww", 1, firstDayOfWeek)  'week 2
```

Output:

> 2/8/2018 12:00:00 AM

Expected Output:

> firstdayofweek: 2/5/2018 
>   lastdayofweek: 2/9/2018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own function based on the info you already have:

```
Public Function FirstDateOfWeekByMonth(ByVal year As Integer, ByVal month as Integer, ByVal weekOfYear As Integer) As DateTime
    Dim jan1 As DateTime = New DateTime(year, month, 1)
    Dim daysOffset As Integer = DayOfWeek.Thursday - jan1.DayOfWeek
    Dim firstThursday As DateTime = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset)
    Dim cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar
    Dim firstWeek As Integer = cal.GetWeekOfYear(firstThursday, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday)
    Dim weekNum = weekOfYear
    If firstWeek <= 1 Then
        weekNum -= 1
    End If

    Dim result = firstThursday.AddDays(weekNum * 7)
    Return result.AddDays(-3)
End Function
```

and the usage:

```
Dim FirstDay as DateTime = FirstDateOfWeekByMonth(2018, 2 , 1) 'First Week of 2018 Feb
Dim LastDay as DateTime = FirstDay.AddDays(4) 'Add 4 days to get Friday

Console.WriteLine("firstdayofweek: " + FirstDay)
Console.WriteLine("lastdayofweek: " + LastDay)
```

gets you:

```
firstdayofweek: 2/5/2018 
lastdayofweek: 2/9/2018
```